# MSVC library linking with MinGW

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker, mingw

I have dll libraries from specific SDK compiled with MSVC '08 while using MinGW. And yes, I've got undefined reference.

```
undefined reference to `Some::NameSpace::Here::Class::method()'
```

In my project I'm using MinGW comliler with Qt (just because I'm making cross-platform app) and Linux libraries provided with SDK works just fine.

1) I've tried using `pexports` tool as in mentioned in MinGW FAQ but got no success. Still same undefined reference (no changes in errors masseges).

In my .def file I've got lines like:

```
?Method@Class@Here@NameSpace@Some@@QAE_NIIGW4eReturnType@234@@Z
```

2) Also `extern "C"` wasn't helpful. I surrounded with it every SDK .h include where it was possible (one header contains template definitions, so I wasn't able to surround it).

Strange thing is, that instead of:

```
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6IClass6Methodci'
```

I got:

```
undefined reference to `Some::NameSpace::Here::Class::method()'
In function `ZN11MyClass21MethodEv':
```

So I think I messed up with name mangling.

Comment: You cannot mix MinGW compiled code with MSVC compiled code.  They don't use the same name mangling algorithm, linker errors are inevitable.  You'll have to ask the SDK author or vendor for a MinGW build.  Or a COM-style interface, the lingua franca for language/compiler interoperability.  Well, good luck with that.

Comment: @HansPassant that is sad :( Well, thank you